# css child selectors targeting specific elements in a table

Tags: css

I am trying to target a specific tr within table using css child selectors.

```
<table class="v65-productDisplay">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td></td></tr>  <--- Target 1
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>  <--- Target 2
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>  <--- Target 3
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here's what I've attempted so far with child selectors:

```
table.v65-productDisplay  tbody tr:first-child {
background-color:red;
}
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:first-child {
background-color:red;
}
table.v65-productDisplay  tbody+tr {
background-color:red;
}
```

So far, none of the child selectors I have tried are able to target the specific tr in the table. It's either all of them, or none of them. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nth-child()`

```
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(4n+1) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

The above will select all your target

Value of n will be `0,1,2,....` that it will select `1st,5th and 9th` `tr`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bX42N/1/)

For more detail visit [**here**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child)

Comment: How does the (4n+1) work? I've never seen this used in nth-child before. Also, I just tried it on my table, and it is selecting all tr's in the table. You can view this at: http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/default.asp

Comment: Thanks for recognizing I was attempting to target every 4th tr, and giving me a solution that I was not even aware existed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for nth-child

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

```
table tr:nth-child(1),
table tr:nth-child(5),
table tr:nth-child(9)
{  
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I tried nth-child, and It seemed to not be working. On further inspection, :nth-child(1) is selecting all tr's in the table, while nth-child(5) and :nth-child(9) are properly selecting only one tr. Why is this? You can view it at http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/default.asp

Comment: @AlexRitter I didn't try on your code. Is it going to be always in these positions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want those three `tr` (if you have more in actual HTML)

```
table.v65-productDisplay tbody tr:nth-child(4n + 1):nth-child(-n + 10) {
    color: black;
}
```

Otherwise, to select every fourth `tr` starting from the first:

```
table.v65-productDisplay tbody tr:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    color: black;
}
```